# COUNTIF Function not correctly identifying Text Pattern specified

Tags: excel

I have a list of tasks, and want to count the number of occurrences. I'm using `=COUNTIF` but getting 0 as a result each time.

For the first formula, I'm expecting 1 and for the second formula I'm expecting 2, but getting 0 for both.

***The tasks are `TEXT`***

[image]

Comment: why are you expecting 1 for the first?  what do you expect `=TEXT(LEFT(O7,10),"0000")` to return?

Answer (score 1):

Use wild cards:

```
=COUNTIF(O7:O11,LEFT(O10,10)&"*")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(O7:O11,10)=LEFT(O10,10)))
```